# Keras ValueError trying to load model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using Anaconda Navigator, Jupyter to be precised.

```
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow import keras
print(tf.__version__)
>>> 1.14.0
```

This is my model

```
def create_model():
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(86, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.0001),input_shape=(129,)),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.Dense(142, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.0001)),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax')
    ])
  return model

model = create_model()

# Display the model's architecture
model.summary()
```

After training,predicting and evaluating my model, I decided to save it using

```
model.save('/Users/Jennifer/myproject/my_model.h5')
```

I checked the directory and folder with the h5py file. And I decided to load it using

```
new_model1 = tf.keras.models.load_model('/Users/Jennifer/myproject/my_model.h5')
```

I got an Error

```
ValueError: Unknown entries in loss dictionary: ['class_name', 'config']. Only expected following keys: ['dense_17']
```

Please help me. What should I do? I have almost spent the whole day trying to solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: I think you're missing a key part of this, what did you pass to compile? When you save the model it will save optimizer/training information. You can pass custom_objects to the load_model to load those objects. Or you can try `load_weights` if you don't want the optimizer stuff.

Comment: @matt for the compile: ```model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0001),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])```.

Comment: If you compile your model before saving it, say model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy']), do you still get this error? Tell me as I am curious if it solves your issue.

Comment: @TimbusCalin No, I didn't get an error message. It worked just fine. This error was after saving the model, I tried loading back again at a separate pyfile using the commands.

Comment: So it solved your problem?

Comment: @TimbusCalin my main goal is to reload the model anytime I need. The funny thing is when I tried the command on google-colab, it worked fine. No error, but when I wrote it on jupyter then the error came.

Comment: @TimbusCalin No, It doesn't. Although the model has been saved and I can see the h5 file in the folder, loading it back is the problem.

Comment: If you create the model, compile it and save it, do you get the error when you load the model? I do get the same error your getting when I do that.

Comment: @matt Yes. I get errors loading it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit of a work around that just loads the weights:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from tensorflow import keras
import os


def create_model():
  model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(86, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.0001),input_shape=(129,)),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.Dense(142, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.0001)),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax')
    ])
  return model

if os.path.exists("junk.h5"):
    model = create_model()
    model.load_weights("junk.h5")

else:
    model = create_model()
    model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0001), loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.save("junk.h5")
```

Another workaround would be to save the model without the optimizer

```
model.save("junk.h5", include_optimizer=False)
```

It looks like the loss function you're using creates a dictionary that has invalid keys. This sounds like a bug in keras/tensorflow. That is why the colab one probably worked because it was using a newer version.

Comment: I tried loading the weights, and they work just fine. I just wanted the entire model, that's all.

Comment: Your experience with colab suggests that if you upgrade tensorflow it might work. Also, saving it w/out the optimizer worked for me, I could then load it with 'load_model'. You might report it as a bug to tensorflow. I suspect it is fixed in a more recent version though.